# Swift 4 range(of:) to Android

Tags: java, android, swift, string, substring

So I am pretty experience with Swift and Java but I am having difficulty translating a small method I made in Swift. It essentially takes a `String` and looks for keys that follow this pattern: `[|field|category|key|]`. It'll loop through the entire `String` until all the instances of this pattern is replaced. An example of what one of these occurrences would be: `[|Name|Attribute|-KzV8eRbaPqmOw4SLa8E|]`. I've begun to translate it below to Android's Java and essentially the whole issue I am having are these lines:

`let end  = newValue.range(of: "]", range: start.upperBound..<newValue.endIndex)`

`let substring = newValue[start.upperBound..<end.lowerBound]`

`let arr = substring.characters.split(separator: "|").map(String.init)`

`if (arr.size() == 3 && substring.components(separatedBy: "|").count-1 == 4)`

Unless I am searching the wrong queries in google I cannot find what `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, and `range` are equivalent to in Android. I do believe because of those I cannot figure out the other line. Any help is much appreciated even if it's just a link to the developer guide or reference. Even if there's not an exact equivalent anything to get me going in the right direction.

```
    if let start = newValue.range(of: "["),let end  = newValue.range(of: "]", range: start.upperBound..<newValue.endIndex) {
       let substring = newValue[start.upperBound..<end.lowerBound]
       let arr = substring.characters.split(separator: "|").map(String.init)
       if (arr.count == 3 && substring.components(separatedBy: "|").count-1 == 4){
          if ((workshop.object(forKey: arr[1]) as? NSDictionary) != nil) {
             if ((workshop.object(forKey: arr[1]) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: arr[2]) as? NSDictionary != nil){
                 newValue = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "[|" + arr[0] + "|" + arr[1] + "|" + arr[2] + "|]", with: String(describing: ((workshop.object(forKey: arr[1]) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: arr[2]) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: arr[0]) as AnyObject))
             }
             else{
                 newValue = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "")
                 newValue = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
             }
          }
          else{
             newValue = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "")
             newValue = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
          }
      }
      else{
          newValue = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "")
          newValue = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
      }
   }
```

Beginning to translate:

```
int start = newValue.indexOf("[");
if let end  = newValue.range(of: "]", range: start.upperBound..<newValue.endIndex) {
     let substring = newValue[start.upperBound..<end.lowerBound]
     let arr = substring.characters.split(separator: "|").map(String.init) //Array
     if (arr.size() == 3 && substring.components(separatedBy: "|").count-1 == 4){
         if (value.containsKey(arr.get(1))){
              Map<String, Object> value1 = (Map<String, Object>) value.get(arr.get(1));
              if (value1.containsKey(arr.get(2))){
                 Map<String, Object> value2 = (Map<String, Object>) value1.get(arr.get(2));
                 newValue = newValue.replace("[|" + arr.get(0) + "|" + arr.get(1) + "|" + arr.get(2), (CharSequence) value2.get(arr.get(0)));
              }
              else{
                 newValue = newValue.replace( "[",  "");
                 newValue = newValue.replace( "]",  "");
             }
     }
     else{
         newValue = newValue.replace( "[",  "");
         newValue = newValue.replace( "]",  "");
     }
 }
```

Comment: If it were me I think I would have attempted to use a regular expression for both the Switft and Android implementations. Have you considered the Pattern and Matcher classes in Java?

Comment: I will look into it. What about the separatedBy? Will the pattern and matcher class of Java have something similar. I think that’s the last part.